# can't submit mail from contact 7 form site using wp mail smtp

Tags: smtp

I have hosted a wordpress site in bigrock server.Then moved it to clients server(Godaddy). Then the contact 7 form stopped working.i have configured the smtp using zoho mail.It is working fine in bigrock but not in Godaddy how to fix this?

Comment: It's hard to help you, because it looks like that you have a problem with your hardware and not with wordpress. Do you contacted the Godadday support? Maybe the smtp port is blocked or something like that.

Comment: I couldn't fix it, so I changed Zoho SMTP and used Google's SMTP. Now it is finally working